# How to create a box plot in MS Excel having access to min, max, Q1, Q3 and mean, but not having access to variables?

Tags: microsoft-excel

As in title. I want to create a box plot in Excel but I have no access to variables. I just have the values for min, max, Q1, Q3 and mean. How to create a box plot using just that? If that's impossible which tool should I use instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arrange your data as Q1, min, max, Q3. Plot as a line chart which gives you four lines and as many points as you have sets of data. Use high-low lines and up/down bars to create the boxes and whiskers. Format as you want them (especially make the high-low lines thicker). Format the original lines to have "no line". Done.

Jon Peltier has some useful info on this in the middle of this article on stock charts (don't try to do this with OOB stock charts!):
https://peltiertech.com/excel-stock-charts/

He also has extensive articles on box plots more generally, although most start from the premise of having other measures such as mean, SD etc, but could still be useful. Also alternatives using column / bar charts which therefore cover horizontal presentation too: https://peltiertech.com/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/